# question on integration of $f(x)\delta(g(x))$

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

I am learning integration with dirac delta. I do not understand this result
by [Maple Dirac](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=dirac)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When I work it by hand, using [known relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)  (here is an image of the page)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Therefore

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi}f\left(  x\right)  \delta\left(  g\left(  x\right)  \right)
dx=\sum_{x_{0}}\frac{f\left(  x_{0}\right)  }{\left\vert g^{\prime}\left(
x_{0}\right)  \right\vert }
$$

Where the sum is over all zeros of $g\left(  x\right)  $ in the integration
interval, which is $\left\{  0,\pi\right\}  $ since $\sin\left(  x\right)  $
is zero at these points, and since $g^{\prime}\left(  x\right)  =\cos\left(
x\right)  $, and $f\left(  x\right)  =\frac{1}{x}$, then I get

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\pi}f\left(  x\right)  \delta\left(  g\left(  x\right)  \right)  dx
& =\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\left\vert \cos\left(  x\right)
\right\vert }+\lim_{x\rightarrow\pi}\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\left\vert \cos\left(
x\right)  \right\vert }\\
& =\infty
\end{align*}

So I am doing something wrong or not using the above result correctly. Is it ok to use the zeros of $g(x)$ if they located at the ends of the interval as in this case? or do the zeros of $g(x)$ have to be inside the interval (i.e. not including end points)? As there are no other zeros inside the interval.

Does this mean if there are no zeros of $g(x)$ in the interval of integration, the integral is therefore zero, since nothing to sum?

How did Maple obtain zero for the above?

**Update**

To answer comment, here is what Maple gives for the two different lower limits

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: What's maples output when you change the interval from $(0,\pi)$ to say either $(0.1,\pi)$ or $(-0.1,\pi)$?

Comment: @snulty I've updated my question with the new limits you asked for. Thanks

Comment: The main problem is that $\delta(\sin x)$ has its support on the integral end points. Therefore you must specify whether the end points should be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it (Maple) isn't taking into account the endpoints since the integral

$$\int_{0.1}^\pi \frac{1}{2x} \delta(\sin(x))dx=0$$

On the other hand, I think there is a way to try and take into account the endpoints by using one of the definitions of the delta function

$$\int_0^b f(x)\delta(x)dx:=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_0^b \frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2} f(x)dx$$

and making a substitution $x=\epsilon y$

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_0^{b/\epsilon}\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon^2y^2+\epsilon^2} f(\epsilon y)\epsilon dy=
\frac{1}{\pi}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_0^{b/\epsilon}\frac{1}{y^2+1} f(\epsilon y) dy\to\frac{f(0)}{\pi}\int_0^\infty\frac{dy}{1+y^2}=\frac{f(0)}{2}$$

So I think one way you could define it would be half the value of the function at the endpoint.